# Extract data from Specific format CSV files

Tags: java, regex, csv

Given such data format of one row in CSV file:

```
'data(g1),data(g1)','data(g2),data(g2),data(g2),,,',,,'data(g5),,,data(g5)',
```

This is in a CSV format, but for a separate group of data, it use

```
''
```

to group them, like:

```
.....'data(g2),data(g2),data(g2),,,'....
```

But there are such awkward situations: a row could miss some groups, and for a group, it could miss some fields. But for all the missing part, it still use a comma to separate them. So each row will always have 6 groups of data. Then how can I got all 6 groups of data properly(even it contains nothing)?

I try to use regular expression like this:

```
String row = <the above data row>;
String[] dataGroups = row.split(',');
```

But this one definitely will not work since in each group of data, it also use comma to separate data. Any effective ways in Java to doing this? It will be awesome if I can have all 6 groups of data stored in a

```
String[] dataGroups
```

which have a length of 6.
Then the rest part will be easy.

Comment: Any reason why you are not using one of the Csv libraries (https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/) or (https://sourceforge.net/projects/supercsv/?source=directory) ???. These libraries can probably handle the format

Comment: I do not think that helps..

Comment: The libraries will treat data in quotes as one field so you do not need to worry about commas embedded in the fields

Comment: Think about this situation: `....,'data(gn),data(gn),subdata='datavalue',data(gn),,',.....` There is a pair of quote inside a pair of quote which you want to access to. @BruceMartin

Comment: uniVocity-parsers' CSV parser can handle the unescaped quotes. [See for yourself](http://www.univocity.com/blogs/news/15989312-univocity-parsers-1-3-0-is-here-with-some-useful-new-features).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. What about a regex like this?

```
('.*')?,('.*')?,('.*')?,('.*')?,('.*')?,('.*')?
```

It's ugly, but it may work correctly...

Per http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html , you'd do something like this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("('.*')?,('.*')?,('.*')?,('.*')?,('.*')?,('.*')?").matcher(row);
m.find();
m.group(1); //gives you the first group on the line; 
//change the index to get the other groups
```

You could then split each group with `.split(',')`

Here's a live version: http://regex101.com/r/jR0iM4/1

Comment: can you be specific about how to use this? Better show some codes

Comment: Does this help explain it?

Comment: Well, this just group those fields with `''`,but it did not capture the empty field.

Comment: It appears to capture the empty field, with `m.group(3);` (run on the example from the OP) -- what exactly are you observing?

Comment: Just curious, why the missing field is represented as 'null' other than ""?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29 says "If the match was successful but the group specified failed to match any part of the input sequence, then null is returned. Note that some groups, for example (a*), match the empty string. This method will return the empty string when such a group successfully matches the empty string in the input. "

Comment: So, since each group has the `?` after it (which means match zero or one times) the ones that aren't present are matched zero times, i.e. they don't match, so it returns null. If you want it to return the empty string, you could make the existing groups non-capturing, and surround them (and the `?`) with an extra layer of parens -- which would then always match, sometimes with the empty string (if the `?` didn't match).

Comment: Assuming this works for you, please accept the answer.

Comment: Think about this situation, in every `('.*')`, it could contains multiple`'....'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64740/discussion-between-jesse-w-at-z-and-liquid).

Answer (score 0):

Is your file format reliable enough to have ' only as start and begin of data group? Then you could remove ' at beginning and end of row, then spilt row by ',' (three symbols) instead of just comma.

Comment: The question is that this is not configurable, it can not be configured to `,'','',`

Comment: I was thinking about 'data(g1),data(g1)','data(g2),data(g2),data(g2),,,',,,'data(g5),,,data(g5)' ---> data(g1),data(g1)','data(g2),data(g2),data(g2),,,',,,'data(g5),,,data(g5) and then this can be split by ',' which is in between groups

Answer (score 0):

I think this becomes more of a sanitization issue. Does all the rows begin and start with single quote (').

If so, you can do the following:

1. Get all the content within quotes via regex.
2. Then for each row, split into columns by splitting on comma.
3. Then record the split groups into List> where the external list are the rows and the nested lists are the columns.
4. You could then adjust this with commas toward the end if the nested list is not of size 6.

In my opinion, this is cleaner to read and consume.

Comment: I can get all the existing content with quotes via regex, but this means I may lose a group with no content. I need to capture it even it is a 'null' group, because the position of each group is important to me. If the content of group 4 is missing, I will achieve 5 groups of contents, but how could I know the which one is missing? The order of the groups is crucial.

Comment: Would empty groups be even represented as ''. Otherwise, how do you know what's missing?

Answer (score -1):

As per one of your comments, you need to parse this:

```
....,'data(gn),data(gn),subdata='datavalue',data(gn),,',.....
```

Only the CSV parser in [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) can parse that. Your input has unescaped quotes inside a quoted value. This will break any other CSV parsing library for Java (feel free to try).

What you have is similar to this:

```
something,"text with "unescaped quotes" here",something else
```

You want this as the output:

```
something
text with "escaped quotes" here
something else
```

You just need to throw your input into uniVocity-parsers' CSV parser

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings =  new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.setParseUnescapedQuotes(true); //this is enabled by default

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(getReader("/examples/bean_test.csv"));
```

More details about this feature [here](http://www.univocity.com/blogs/news/15989312-univocity-parsers-1-3-0-is-here-with-some-useful-new-features).

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).