# Java Match Content In Quotes

Tags: java, regex

[Extract data from Specific format CSV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808092/extract-data-from-specific-format-csv-files)

The data format is list in the above link.

Basically, I want to extract all the field with quotes like：

```
'data0,data1,data2,,,','.........'
```

And I use regular expression like this:

```
String subrow = row.replaceFirst("'\\w.*?',",",");
```

this will always match the first contents in a pair of quotes.

However, there is a situation like this:

for example

```
data1 = "encoding = 'utf-8'"
```

and still if I use the method above, it will match:

```
'data0,encoding='
```

other than

```
'data0,encoding='utf-8',data2,,,'
```

Then how can the regular expression modified to match the content in a pair of quotes, even if there is another pair of quotes in it? (zero or one pair of quotes)

PS: a text will be used in testing:

```
'1415561780,84,0,130,52','0,0,0,97517573,0,0,0,0,0,,,','corpvpn,ac103f20,57771,42eb9375,80,0','4,http%3a%2f%2flenovoappssystemupdateprod.112.2o7.net%2fb%2fss%2flenovoappssystemupdateprod%2f6,,0,0,,text/xml; encoding='utf-8',595,207,595,161,595,0,1,0,0,0,ac10ff1b,18604,42eb9375,80,0,','200,text/xml,text/xml,64,64,481,64,472,64,0,0,0',,,,,
```

please pay attention that there is an:

```
 encoding='utf-8'
```

inside the fourth pair of quotes.

Comment: OK, perhaps it should be `\\w`, I want to match the a digit or letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem you want to allow `='foo'` to be part of match which is also inside `'...'`. In that case you can try with this regex

```
'\\w(=\\s*'[^']*'|[^'])*'
```

Some explanation of regex

- `|` represents `OR`
- construct like `[abc]` is [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) - it will match one character which in this example is either `a` `b` or `c`
- `[^abc]` is negated character class - it will accept any character which is ***not*** `a` `b` nor `c`
- `\\s` represents whitespaces (for instance space, `\t`, `\n`, `\r`...)
- `\\w` represents characters which can be used in words (`0-9` `a-z` `A-Z` and underscore `_`)
- `*` is quantifier which means that element before it can appear zero-or-more-times like `ab*a` can accept `aa` `aba` `abba` `abbba` and so on.

Now to explain my regex

```
'\w(=\s*'[^']*'|[^'])*'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- `[^']*` represents zero or more characters which are not `'`. If we surround it with `'` like `'[^']*'` this will represent text which starts and ends with `'` and has no more `'` inside, so in case of text like `'foo' bar 'baz'` it can match `'foo'` `'baz'`. It is similar to `'.*?'`.
- but instead of simple `'[^']*'` I decided to add case where instead of *non-`'`-character* between first `'` and last `'` we can also accept series of `='...'` (like `='utf-8'`).

Demo:

```
String s ="'1415561780,84,0,130,52','0,0,0,97517573,0,0,0,0,0,,,','corpvpn,ac103f20,57771,42eb9375,80,0','4,http%3a%2f%2flenovoappssystemupdateprod.112.2o7.net%2fb%2fss%2flenovoappssystemupdateprod%2f6,,0,0,,text/xml; encoding='utf-8',595,207,595,161,595,0,1,0,0,0,ac10ff1b,18604,42eb9375,80,0,','200,text/xml,text/xml,64,64,481,64,472,64,0,0,0',,,,,";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'\\w(=\\s*'[^']*'|[^'])*'");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
'1415561780,84,0,130,52'
'0,0,0,97517573,0,0,0,0,0,,,'
'corpvpn,ac103f20,57771,42eb9375,80,0'
'4,http%3a%2f%2flenovoappssystemupdateprod.112.2o7.net%2fb%2fss%2flenovoappssystemupdateprod%2f6,,0,0,,text/xml; encoding='utf-8',595,207,595,161,595,0,1,0,0,0,ac10ff1b,18604,42eb9375,80,0,'
'200,text/xml,text/xml,64,64,481,64,472,64,0,0,0'
```

Comment: Can you be specific about `='[^']*'|[^']`? What does this partial regular expression mean?

Comment: @Liquid Can you specify which part is not clear (unfamiliar) for you? `|` represents `OR` operator, `[...]` is character class, `[^...]` is negated character class.

Comment: I did not have a try for it, but I want to confirm my problem, another pair of quotes not always occurs in a quotes of content. This means, the regular expression should be able to match both situations. Situation one: `'content'`, situation two:`''content''`

Comment: @Liquid Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean with `''content''`. Could you edit your question to provide some actual example of input and explanation of which results (regex matches) are correct and which aren't?

Comment: @Liquid What confuses me in `''content''` is that according to your regex you wanted first character after `'` to be alphanumeric while in this case character after first `'` is another `'` which is not alphanumeric.

Comment: sometimes, it will be only content inside a pair of quotes like `'12,12,34,,,'` while sometimes, a certain field of value inside a pair of quotes could contain another pair of quotes, like `'12,12,encoding='utf-8',13'`,can your regular expression match both situation?

Comment: @Liquid Examples you just gave should be handled by regex from my answer.

Comment: @Liquid OK, take your time. Let me know if it will not work (example of text which failed your test would be helpful). I have few ideas of how this can be rewritten but they depend on different assumptions which will need to be confirmed.

Comment: @Liquid I updated my answer with code I used to test your example and from my point of view it seems that it works fine (unless I misunderstood your requirements). Can you post how you tested it, what result you got and what you expected?

Comment: I find your result is right. Still, I am not very familiar with regular expression, if you can explain more details about what you did inside the `()`, I will accept your answer. Thanks! I know there is an `OR` operation, but what's them about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64665/discussion-between-liquid-and-pshemo).

Comment: @Liquid I added some explanation. If you will have some questions about it I will try to answer it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I asked so much, but this is too tricky for me. Can you change the regular expression so that I can also match `'Dunks',12,13,,'`, note that this is only one quote in a pair of quotes. So basically I need to deal with both single quote and double quotes situation in a pair of quotes

Comment: @Liquid I can try but you need to provide me some informations about when `'` inside `'....'` should be treated as non-special-`'`-which-should-not-end-this-quote.